# Popup Server File Browser/Picker for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, helper

Before I start coding this from scratch, I need to see if someone has run across a control/Helper that does what I need.

I have set up a Telerik control called image browser to let the client upload and manage images under a specific folder on the server and this works very well.

Now I need to allow them to pick one of the files that they have uploaded. This selection happens in many pages so I want to implement something like a popup date picker except it is a popup file picker. This picker is browsing files on the SERVER not on the CLIENT. When the client picks a file, it will put the path into a text box for saving as part of the form.

I know how I can write this if I have to so that is not the issue. The question I have is has someone already written something that does this to save me the effort?

I have researched this and only found articles that are many years old.

Thank you for your help.

Earl

Comment: Please post if you found something.  I need something similar.  I just need to allow the users to open a picker that shows the server's filesystem and to set the path they select to change a default setting.  I've seen a ton of file pickers on Python web apps, but I don't know much about Python frameworks and was hoping for a dot net solution.

Comment: I'm hoping to get at this in the next month or so. Ill most my solution once I'm done...

Comment: OK, I built one of these and it seams to be working well. Its not really fancy but does the job. Now I need to isolate it into its own project and post it somewhere...